# Count the position in a group in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, uniqueidentifier

I would like to use a formula to automatically set a position of a group in a table entry.

This can also be seen as an autoincremental ID which needs to be unique only in the group it is associated with.

The formula would generate the numbers in the Position column as pictured below:

[image: Target]

Is there any way to do this without using VBA?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following in Column C and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2, A2)
```